Multivariable calculus - continuity and (partial) derivatives

Prove for the point (1, -2) of the function f
$$ f : \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R : (x,y) \mapsto  \begin{cases} \frac {5(x-1)^3+3(y+2)^3}{(x-1)^2+2(y+2)^2} & \text{for } (x,y) \ne (1,-2)  \\ 0 & \text{elsewhere } \end{cases} $$ if f is

continuous
partially differentiable
totally differentiable
continuously partially differentiable


Alright, I proved the discontinuity already (using sequences and garnering different results), which lead me to the assumption that f is also not totally differnetiable at the specific point (which I hope is correct?).
And now I wanted to tackle the partial derivatives.
Starting with derivating for x, I got : $$ \frac {15(x-1)^2}{(x-1)^2+2(y+2)^2} - \frac {2(5(x-1)^3+3(y+2)^3)(x-1)}{((x-1)^2+2(y+2)^2)^2} $$ (and I already checked that I got the derivative correct.)
Now to the actual problem: evaluating for the actual points.
Because if I put in $$y = -2$$ and simplify, I get
$$ \frac {15(x-1)^2}{(x-1)^2} - \frac {2(5(x-1)^3)(x-1)}{((x-1)^2)^2} $$
And gathering the terms, it turns to
$$ \frac {15(x-1)^2}{(x-1)^2} - \frac {10(x-1)^4)}{((x-1)^4} $$
and now i can cancel the term and get $$15-10=5.$$
However, if I put in $$x=1$$ beforehand, I get $$\frac {0}{0}$$
,which isn't the same.
Now I read somewhere on here that it doesn't matter when you set one of the points you're not taking the derivative for, but something is definitely off here.
I have to do a handful of similar problems and I'd like to get a clear understanding of the process beforehand. Any help and heads-ups are appreciated :)

For the derivatives you should make the limit of the incremental ratio, not perform the calculation of the partial derivatives

Because it's not actually defined there? Or another reason?

Because of the definition of partial derivative, and because the expression that define the function in points different from $(1,-2)$ is not defined there, and you would like to calculate partial derivatives just there
